# Showing hidden textboxes as they are filled

Tags: javascript

I have a page of thirty text boxes with Id's roughly correlating to **_Q0/_Q1/_Q2/_Q3** etc.

I'm trying to design a JS code that will hide all but the first box, and then will reveal the next textbox as the previous one is filled in.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    for(var i=1;i<30;i++){
    var t = i
        document.getElementById("_Q" + t).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    };

    var idNumber = 0
    document.getElementById("_Q"+idNumber).onKeyUp(function(){return boxAdder()});

    function boxAdder(){
        idNumber = idNumber+1;
        document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).style.visibility = 'block';
        document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).onKeyUp(function(){return boxAdder()});
    };      

});
```

So far all the boxes are hidden excluding the first box. However when I write into the first box nothing happens. I'm not entirely sure where this code is going wrong.

Edit: sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8b7pH/3/

Solved! Here is the final code:

```
$(function () {
    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    var t = i;
        document.getElementById("_Q" + t).style.visibility = 'hidden';
       // document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).onkeyup = function(){console.log("hi"); return boxAdder(t+1);};
    }

    var idNumber = 0;
    document.getElementById("_Q0").onkeyup = function(){console.log("hi"); return boxAdder(0);};

    function boxAdder(numm){
        console.log("ho");
        //idNumber = idNumber+1;
        document.getElementById("_Q" + numm).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("_Q" + numm).onkeyup = function(){return boxAdder(numm+1);};
    }


});
```

Comment: One a side note - why are u using plain-vanilla JS (getElementById, style etc.) when you clearly have jQuery?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility - visibility can be set to visible, hidden, collapse, *not* block.

Comment: `"string"+number` for ids is almost always indicative of a bigger problem. Learn about separation of concerns and structuring a web app.

Comment: Where does this code live? You're defining an anonymous function on the first line; is it inside a larger block that causes this function to run?

Comment: A mix between understanding and consistency of standards at work. I understand JS better than JQuery, and I had some earlier issues with this function which led me to break it down into almost entirely JS, removing any JQuery I had before.

Comment: @Scott every place I looked before said to use block. However, after trying 'visible' that also doesn't work.

Comment: @Charles. It just runs on loading the web page is all. There is a few other JS files but they run independently of this one (and are huge).

Comment: @Benjamin, I want all of the elements to do the same thing so not sure why I would need to separate them out individually?

Comment: @Scironic Block is when you set style.display.  Not sure why you're not getting the results you want now.  Have you put a `console.log` into `boxAdder` and your `onKeyUp` anonymous function, just to make sure things are being hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the fiddle.  I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/8b7pH/6/) it to a working one.

Here's the code:

```
$(function () {
    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    var t = i;
        document.getElementById("_Q" + t).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    var idNumber = 0;
    document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).onkeyup = function(){console.log("hi"); return boxAdder();};

    function boxAdder(){
        console.log("ho");
        idNumber = idNumber+1;
        document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).onkeyup = function(){return boxAdder();};
    }


});
```

The significant change was the syntax for `onkeyup`: `element.onkeyup = function()`.  Other than that, there were a bunch of missing semicolons that didn't matter.  I added `console.log`s that can obviously be removed.

**EDIT**

Edgar found a valid bug, so I put in a [fix](http://jsfiddle.net/8b7pH/8/).  Basically, remove the onkeyup event as soon as it's called:

```
document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).onkeyup = function(){this.onkeyup = null; return boxAdder();};

function boxAdder(){
    idNumber = idNumber+1;
    document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("_Q" + idNumber).onkeyup = function(){this.onkeyup = null; return boxAdder();};
}
```

Note the new `this.onkeyup = null;` in two places.

Comment: That's almost embarassing considering the ';'s

Comment: Javascript doesn't really care about `;` in most cases, but the jslint check in the fiddle did.  It made a red dot, so I got rid of it.  :-)  (Of course, to avoid the times when it *does* care, it's always best to pretend `;` is necessary.)

Comment: thanks it does work. Although I realised my idNumber method isn't perfect by any means.

Comment: Doesn't work. If you press key many times, shows more textboxes

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado Thanks.  I posted a fix.  Fwiw, your function is much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
$(function () {
    var $boxes = $("[id^=_Q]").hide().keyup(function(){   //Hide all, then attach keyup
       var i = $(this).index();  //Index of the box being typed
       $boxes.eq(i+1).show();    //Get and show next textbox
    });
    $boxes.first().show();  //Show next textbox
});
```

Btw `$("[id^=_Q]")` selects all elements whose `id` starts with `_Q`

Working OK here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/8b7pH/7/

Cheers

Comment: I keep on seeing that. Shame the actual ID's have the number stuck in the middle ("_Q0_Q0_Q0_Q0_Qx_Q0"). I'll put it to use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you assign a function to the onchange event of the text boxes, and give each one an id as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    function textChange(){
    // Get the number of the caller's id
    var inputNumber = $(event.target).attr('id').split("txt")[1];

    // Select the next input by increasing the inputNumber and set its "display" attr to block
    $("#txt" + ++inputNumber).css("display", "block");
}
</script>
<from>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" onchange="textChange()" />
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="txt2" onchange="textChange()" />
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="txt3" onchange="textChange()" />
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="txt4" onchange="textChange()" />
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="txt5" onchange="textChange()" />
</form>
```

A working example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WChd8/

Comment: I can only manipulate the HTML indirectly using JavaScript so I'm stuck with the ID's and can only add onChange attributes through JS. That is just $("#id").change(function) though isn't it?

Comment: If you need to add the onchange function through javascript code you can loop on all inputs of type text and change their IDs  or names or even add classes to use the same trick on...check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/WChd8/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript only approach, based on what you already had, that also checks for the content written in the input. If is blank, it hides the next one again.

```
for(var i=0;i<30;i++){
    var element = document.getElementById("_Q" + i);
    if(element != null)
    {
        element.onkeyup = function() {
            var next = parseInt(this.id.replace("_Q", "")) + 1;
            document.getElementById("_Q" + next).style.visibility = (this.value != "" ? "visible" : "hidden");
        }
    }
    if(i>0)
        element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
```