# How to insert another input html when writing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have 4 input box's like this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" value="Text 1" id="txt" />
<input type="text" name="txtName2" value="Text 2" id="txt" />
<input type="text" name="txtName3" value="Text 3" id="txt" />
<input type="text" name="txtName4" value="Text 4" id="txt" />
```

But I only want to show one at a time.
For example I write text on first input textName1, and the on interface, show the another input textName2

Comment: show us what you have tried till yet

Comment: jQuery hide/show would be my first thought.  Control it with JavaScript.  That's how DOM is manipulated in the browser.  Write handlers for the onblur event to display each one in turn.

Comment: Each element has to have unique id!

Comment: All 3 questions above work very well. thanks! Problem Solved

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please do not edit it into the question. Instead, vote up/mark an answer below which solved your problem. If none of those answers were on the mark, you can post your own answer instead.

Comment: Sorry, new member, already my account is block! And also have only 14 positive votes, so I still can't vote! sorry.

Comment: I check again, I only have 14 votes, I need 15 to vote answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code, just to demonstrate the idea:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="txtName" id="Text0" id="txt" />
    <input type="text" name="txtName2" id="Text1" id="txt" />
    <input type="text" name="txtName3" id="Text2" id="txt" />
    <input type="text" name="txtName4" id="Text3" id="txt" />

    <script>
        for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
            var element = document.getElementById("Text" + i);
            if(element != null)
            {
                element.onkeyup = function() {
                    var next = parseInt(this.id.replace("Text", "")) + 1;
                    document.getElementById("Text" + next).style.visibility = (this.value != "" ? "visible" : "hidden");
                }
            }
            if(i>0)
                element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Give the inputs sequential unique ids.
It has been discussed today, on another post:

[Showing hidden textboxes as they are filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001401/showing-hidden-textboxes-as-they-are-filled/21002058#21002058)

Comment: I use this:$(function () {
      var $boxes = $("[id^=_Q]").hide().keyup(function(){   //Hide all, then attach keyup
         var i = $(this).index();  //Index of the box being typed
         $boxes.eq(i+1).show();    //Get and show next textbox
      });
      $boxes.first().show();  //Show next textbox
      });
  });

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want to show the current one and the next input element. This can easily be done in jQuery

So you can have this in your HTML

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" value="Text 1" id="txt1" class="inputs "/>
<input type="text" name="txtName2" value="Text 2" id="txt2" class="noshow inputs" />
<input type="text" name="txtName3" value="Text 3" id="txt2" class="noshow inputs" />
<input type="text" name="txtName4" value="Text 4" id="txt3" class="noshow inputs" />
```

and in your CSS

```
.noshow{
    display:none;
}
```

And then, in your jQuery

```
$(".inputs").focus(function(){
   $(this).next().show();
});
```

Then, to hide the element you are no longer focused on

```
$(".inputs").blur(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cmSF/4/)**

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" value="Text 1" id="txt1" class="inputs  hide show"/>
<input type="text" name="txtName2" value="Text 2" id="txt2" class="hide " />
<input type="text" name="txtName3" value="Text 3" id="txt2" class="hide " />
<input type="text" name="txtName4" value="Text 4" id="txt3" class="hide " />
```

**CSS**:

```
.hide{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.show{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
   $(this).next().addClass("show");
});
$("input").blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("show");    
});
```